# check if the names are duplicate in email column

Tags: r

i have a data frame like below, now i want to check if name before @ are duplicate, if duplicate then mutate new column

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhop","kol","noi","gurg"),
                 email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","rahul.singh@gmail.com","",NA,NA,"","sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.singh@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","praveen.thakur@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","lokesh.sharma@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"),
                 name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))


Email = "email" 

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    `13. duplicate name with mailid` = str_extract(Email,  "([^@]+)"),
    `13. duplicate name with mailid` = ifelse(duplicated(`13. duplicate name with mailid`, fromLast = 1)==TRUE,"13. Duplicate domain exist with this name","")
  )
```

but i want to ignore blank cells and NA cells any solution for this...??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work: Have made change to your data, made "rahul.singh" appear twice.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(name = str_extract(email, '.*(?=@)')) %>% group_by(name) %>% 
mutate(duplicate_name = case_when(n() >1 & !is.na(name) ~ 'Duplicate domain exists with this name', TRUE ~ ''))
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   name [12]
   ID        city  email                      name           duplicate_name                          
   <chr>     <chr> <chr>                      <chr>          <chr>                                   
 1 "DEV2962" del   "akash.dev@gmail.com"      akash.dev      ""                                      
 2 "KTN2252" mum   "rahul.singh@gmail.com"    rahul.singh    "Duplicate domain exists with this name"
 3 "ANA2719" nav   ""                         NA             ""                                      
 4 "ITI2624" pun    NA                        NA             ""                                      
 5 "DEV2698" bang   NA                        NA             ""                                      
 6 "HRT2921" chen  ""                         NA             ""                                      
 7 ""        triv  "rahul.singh@email.com"    rahul.singh    "Duplicate domain exists with this name"
 8 "KTN2624" vish  "kunal.singh@gmail.com"    kunal.singh    ""                                      
 9 "ANA2548" del   "lakhan.tomar@gmail.com"   lakhan.tomar   ""                                      
10 "ITI2535" mum   "praveen.thakur@gmail.com" praveen.thakur ""                                      
11 "DEV2732" bang  "sarman.ali@gmail.com"     sarman.ali     ""                                      
12 "HRT2837" vish  "zuber.khan@gmail.com"     zuber.khan     ""                                      
13 "ERV2951" bhop  "giriraj.singh@gmail.com"  giriraj.singh  ""                                      
14 "KTN2542" kol   "lokesh.sharma@gmail.com"  lokesh.sharma  ""                                      
15 "ANA2813" noi   "pooja.pawar@gmail.com"    pooja.pawar    ""                                      
16 "ITI2210" gurg  "nikita.sharma@gmail.com"  nikita.sharma  ""
```

Comment: as i have million records in database and it is taking alot time to execute , do we have any other simple solution...??